How can I get the currently selected objects in the outliner, if they are hidden?
I am making a script where I need to get the currently selected objects in the outliner, this works fine in most cases with bpy.context.selected_objects.
The problem is that it does not work if the objects are hidden, I can get the active object with bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active, even if it's hidden, but not all the other selected objects. bpy.context.view_layer.objects.selected does not seem to work either?
How can I get the selected objects?


Hover over the Outliner and hit the '.' (period) key. Not sure about using Python for it though. The keybinding is 'outliner.show_active' if that helps.

First of all, you need to know, that selection in Outliner is not the same as in viewport. It is in sync, only because this option is enabled:

Then this option is disabled, different sets of objects and collections can be selected in different Outliners. Since the list of selected collections is different for each area, it can only be obtained through the context of this area.
So with some modifications from this post and this post, I have ended up with the script:
import bpy

override_context = bpy.context.copy()
area = [area for area in bpy.context.screen.areas if area.type == "OUTLINER"][0]
override_context['area'] = area
override_context['region'] = area.regions[-1]
 
with bpy.context.temp_override(**override_context):
    selection = bpy.context.selected_ids
    selected = [sel for sel in selection if sel.rna_type.name != 'Collection']
    print(selected)

First part of the script just search for outliner area. You can run operator from outliner, in this case skip this part.
The context can be accessed using context override. Then we can check the list of selected ID-objects in this context through the selected_ids list.
Note, that in Outliner not only objects, but also collections can be selected, so we filter them out.

Wow! Thank you so much! This actually seems to work!!! I have looked everywhere, and this is the first time I see a answere that works! Thanks a bunch Crantiz!

I think the operator is overkill in this case, you can access the selected ids directy with bpy.context. See https://blenderartists.org/t/how-can-i-get-the-currently-selected-objects-in-the-outliner-if-they-are-hidden/1551041/9?u=gorgious

Thanks, it works
